# when i am installing android studio it displays an error

Tags: android, android-studio

> This computer meets the requirements for HAXM, but Intel
>   Virtualization Technology (VT-x) is not turned on. HAXM cannot be
>   installed until VT-x is enabled. Please refer to the Intel HAXM
>   documentation for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Well I just handled this error 3 days ago, you must go to your BIOS, find security or advanced settings and enable there Intel Virtualization Technology. Save restart and try install HAXM again.

Regards

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Turn virtualization on in BIOS settings.

Step 2: Control Panel -> "Programs" -> "Turn Windows features on or off" (under "Programs and Features") and locate "Hyper-V", uncheck it, reboot.

Step 3:If you have any AntiVirus Right click on their icon and turn protection/running mode off for some time, for example 1 hour.

Final step and the main: Go to MyPC / right click / Advanced System Settings / Advanced / In Performance click SETTINGS / Data Execution Prevention and enable DEP for all programs and services.

I hope this helps. It has worked for few people.

Comment: there is no hyper-v in turn windows features on or off